# grouped bar dataset in djanog template loop

Tags: django, chart.js

i would like to draw a grouped bar from chart js using django which currently works fine. Actually i do manually. but i need to draw a grouped bar through for loop(data,label,background-color).

Actual

```
label_list=[2019,2020]
color_list=['#e75e72','#3396ff']
data_list=[[282,314,106,502,107,111],[86,350,411,340,635,809]]

datasets: [
        { 
          label: {{label_list.0|safe}}, 
          backgroundColor: '{{color_list.0|safe}}',
          data:{{data_list.0|safe}} , 
        }, 
        { 
          label: {{label_list.1|safe}}, 
          backgroundColor: '{{color_list.1|safe}}',
          data: {{data_list.1|safe}} ,
        }, 
        ]
```

i really do not have any idea to make it dynamically.

i need something like

```
{% for x in label_list %}
 {{
label:label_list.forloop.counter[x],
background-color:color_list.forloop.counter[x],
data:data_list.forloop.counter[x]
}}//forloop.counter0,forloop.counter1
{% endfor %}
```

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than processing the values in template, why not you build the dataset in view and send it as context, like this:

```
datasets = list()

for label, color, data in zip(label_list, color_list, data_list):
    value_dict = {
         'label': label,
         'backgroundColor' : color,
         'data': data
    }
    datasets.append(value_dict)

context = {'datasets': json.dumps(datasets)}  # use 'import json' on top of the file
return render('template.html', context)
```

Then use it directly in your template like this:

```
<script>
    var dataset = {{ datasets }}
    // rest of the code
</script>
```

Comment: thanx for your valuable reply Ruddra. i get output like 

    [[{"label": 2019, "backgroundColor": "#3396ff", "data": [10, 17, 75]}], [{"label": 2020, "backgroundColor": "#ff8c1a", "data": [66, 8, 17]}]]. 

But i do not know how to iterate it. 

    var mydataset = {{ datasets|safe }}
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: {{locataires_list|safe}},//nom locataires 6
            datasets: [ mydataset  ]
          },
Is it correct way?

Comment: You should get the value like this `[{"label": 2019, "backgroundColor": "#3396ff", "data": [10, 17, 75]}, {"label": 2020, "backgroundColor": "#ff8c1a", "data": [66, 8, 17]}]`, You should not get a list inside a list.

Comment: hi tried. but get some syntax error. is this correct way to implement the code? var mydataset =  {{datasets}};//error : declaration or statement unexpected"
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['data1','data2','data3'],
        datasets: [ 
        {
          mydataset
        }      
        ]
      },

Comment: I got the solution. it was a simple syntax error. thanx for your help. great keep it up.